# Cache Angular module compilation in Travis-CI

Tags: angular, travis-ci

Every time when I run my Angular builds in Travis it has to compile all the Angular modules to ESM5

```
Compiling @angular/core : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/common : module as esm5
etc.
```

I wondered if there was a way to cache these compiled modules using Travi-CI's [cache](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in angular ivy, we need to compile libraries so that they are compatible.

This is done by the `ngcc` util.
If angular-cli finds libraries that have not been run through ngcc it will do it on the fly.

You can tell ngcc to do this by running

`ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points`

The output of ngcc is stored within `node_modules` so as long as you cache `node_modules` and call the above when running in CI you should be fine.

I suggest adding it as a post install hook

in your `package.json` file add

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It needed a little bit of tweaking for me, namely: replacing `--properties es2015 browser module main` with `--properties module`. I personally don't have any experience with `ngcc` so it was mainly a lot of guesswork to get it to work in the end.

Comment: Doesn't this still get cleared out when you run `npm ci` in travis?